# App stuck till save data into core data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, database, core-data

I am new to core data in iOS and i have got around 5000 record with multiple key value .
I want to save it in core data storage in backgorund so app will not stuck. I have saved it already and the code is implemented in Appdelegate.swift class but when app run its stuck till the data load from the API and save into core data storage.

Here is my Code :-

```
     let tempArray = NSMutableArray(array : data!)
 for i in 0 ..< tempArray.count {
                    print(i)
                    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                        return
                    }
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        self.moc = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                    }
 let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Product", into: self.moc!) as! Product
 if (tempArray.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "id") != nil {
                        entity.setValue((tempArray.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "id")  as! NSNumber , forKey: "id")
                    }
  DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    do {
                       try self.moc?.save()
                   } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
```

i have tried with try self.moc?.save() to put in dispatch async but its giving error

Comment: This is not how core data works. You need to first follow some tutorial. Try to understand how `performBlock` method works. https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with OperationQueue

```
let op = OperationQueue()
op.addOperation {
  //Your task goes here
  do {
     try self.moc.save()
  } 
  catch {
       fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
  }
}
```

**method 2**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                   self.moc.save()
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
}
```

**Do like this**

```
moc.perform {
  if let a = (tempArray.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "id") {
        let obj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: moc)
        obj.setValue(a as! NSNumber , forKey: "id")
  }
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     do {
       try self.moc.save()
     } catch {
       fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
     }
}
```

Comment: i am saving entire data in appdelegate but when i perform any tap nothing happens

Comment: I have tried both ways. And both works perfectly fine for me. I have also used fetch data from both ways and it works for me. Try putting a break point there.

Comment: @RahulAnand I have updated the answer for u. put code in moc.perform

Comment: yes i have tried with both way but still got stucked . can i send you that function?

Comment: @RahulAnand Look at the code again. I have optimized it for you

Comment: try putting your code in viewcontroller and give it a try

Comment: actually i can't because i am already calling two API in my view controller which is root view controller too

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using a single main-thread context.  ManagedObjectContexts are not thread safe so they must be run on the thread they were created on.  Main-thread managedObjectContext are great for reading - because you generally display your data on the main thread - but they are terrible for writing because you would rather that done in the background. Queues or dispatch async won't fix it, because the context must be executed on the main thread.

Having a single context for the application only works if your app is super small and simple.  In the past there were many setups on how to have a core-data setup with background saving and have the main context for displaying data.  Since iOS 10 there is `NSPersistentContainer` which is a automatic setup for a great core-data stack which solves all theses issues.

If you are only supporting iOS 10+ then I strong recommend using `NSPersistentContainer`.  This is how you use it: Treat the `viewContext` as readonly and **never** write data on the main thread.  Only write data using `performBackgroundTask:` using the context that is given to your block of code.  Don't pass managedObject into or out of the these blocks.  If you need to modify a managedObject on the `viewContext` save its objectID and refetch in the background task.  Also in you core-data setup set the (`viewContext` to automatically merge changes `self.persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;`)